# Will sharing PS Plus still work on diffrent servers? (E.g. US and Singapore)

Tags: ps4, playstation-plus

I made a US account on my PS4 and I plan to buy PS Plus Asia so it will be cheaper. Then I made a Singapore account. Can I ask if sharing PS Plus will still work on different servers?

Answer (score 1):

PS Plus is associated with a single PSN account. Two different PSN users on the same physical PS4 can play each others' installed games, but the appropriate PSN account must be logged in to install the game.

Comment: No I mean for online? Tnx 

Comment: No, if it's for online, then only your PS Plus will only work for the Singapore account. You'll need a separate PS Plus for your US account.